# Change state for checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using this component user can mark it favourite. If it was already marked then the `checkbox` will render as `checked`. `handleFavourite` makes an api call to mark the component favourite or otherwise. This is a stateless component as of now.

The problem I am facing is, when user clicks on these checkboxes the `checked` property does not change because the value `favourite` is being passed to the component as a prop. How do I make this work so that the checkboxes render as checked or not depending on the history and update themselves when user clicks on them.

```
createElement('input', {
  checked: favourite ? true : false,
  className: 'mark_favourite',
  type: 'checkbox',
  title: 'Mark favourite to make this public',
  onClick: () => handleFavourite(thingtomarkfav)}),
) 

handleFavourite = ({ id, favorite }) => {
  const newFav = (!favorite) ? 1 : 0;
  setFavourite(id, newFav);
};

export function setFavourite(id, status) {
  return fetch(`/things/${id}/favourite/${status}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials,
  }).then(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: You can update the value of `favourite` in states in your `handleFavourite` function

Comment: Please show your `handleFavourite` event handler method. And if favourite is being passed as prop, how are you using this.props.favourite in the component?

Comment: @SagarJajoriya: Modifying props is not something I want happening.

Comment: Do you see the checkbox as checked after a page reload? Because your component is not re-rendered after you make a `POST` request. Use `setState` to trigger a re-render.